How to read this strange comma-delimited file with randomly added quotes
I'm receiving from a banking app CSV file and I can't figure out how to manage it. fgets function gives me the result below:
"2024-03-01, ""abc"", ""abc2"", 40, ""abc3"", """", """"";;

As you can see there are two semi-colons at the end, the rest is wrapped in apostrophes and then there are values with or without doubled-up double apostrophes. So I did this:
$line = fgets($file,);
$line = substr($line, 0, -5);
$line = substr($line, 1);
$line = str_replace('""', '"', $line);
$keys = str_getcsv(mb_convert_encoding($line, "UTF-8", "ISO-8859-2"), ",");

Well, it works fine, but there is probably a better solution than doing this workaround solution for every line.
EDIT. It doesn't work fine since I checked CSV files generated from other dates. The pattern is even more uncommon:
"2024-04-19,""2024-04-19"",""abc"",""-100.00"",""Title";" Comments"",""""";

Well, the best part here is that the semi-colons are usually included, but randomly there is a line without them.
So now my solution is useless and I'm confused even more.

That is a ridiculous line for a CSV file. Completely unacceptable for anything that has to do with banking.

Well, you can just get rid of any quotes (=double apostrophes), since they don't seem to serve any purpose, trim off any semi-column, and then hope that the commas can be used to extract the data out of the line.

My Excel cannot make any sense from a file with this line. Did you actually try to open it with Excel?

I think the method you implemented is the simplest and best method, But there is no need to use these conversions(Considering that changing the encoding of string can cause the loss of part of the data).
I have written this code in a simpler way:
$line = "2024-03-01, \"\"abc\"\", \"\"abc2\"\", 40, \"\"abc3\"\", \"\"\"\", \"\"\"\"";

$explodedArr = explode(',',$line);
$resultArray = [];
foreach($explodedArr as $arrElement){
    $resultArray[] = str_replace('"', "", $arrElement);
}

print_r($resultArray);

